# Reflect-metadata index.d.ts，I‘m confused by function metadata type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I use reflect-metadata this package, I found this type. But I don't know what it means, and this function signature.

```
    function metadata(metadataKey: any, metadataValue: any): {
        (target: Function): void;
        (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol): void;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript syntax is tricky, you should try the code in TS Playground and experiment to understand it.
Checkout this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCBKIAZhOAC7wDeAUPLfIQK6JikCWA9ovGqVMFLwAUPPgKgBpEAE8AXPCiIpAGm4he-XgDUoEBiDkKpASjnU65%20IN4wA5mrkAxJiw6IT8AG7tWwANw0LWitYO1I5AHkAIwArMhVrUMlZeHRSGFZEG3gAHxSpFEj2CHcvH39zAF9-CqoAsE5U7ngAXngCYjIAOhENKEEAclIMUn6VQeH%20o38AlEF6xHQikE6IdhspmcEKCrGAa2lJ33gAemP4IA)

Let's go back to your code:

```
declare namespace Reflect {
    function metadata(metadataKey: any, metadataValue: any): {
        (target: Function): void;
        (target: Object, targetKey: string | symbol): void;
    };
}

const m = Reflect.metadata('test', 'test');

m(console.log); // TS suggest m(target: Function): void
m({}, 'test'); // TS suggest m(target: Object, targetKey: string | symbol): void
```

That's pretty much arguments overload.
Hence we can deduce about the signature of function metadata is

1. metadata will return a function (let's called it fn)
2. fn can take another function as argument
3. Or fn can take an object (target) and (a string or symbol) as another argument

Comment: appreciate it! So I can think this way that Reflect.metadata return overload functions?

Comment: @user13368409 yes, you can think of it that way